# strrev function inserts a line feed character in the first element of a string array

Tags: c, string, reverse, linefeed

So basically:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    //test strrev
    char s[50];
    char s2[50];
    char *ps;
    int i=0;
    printf("String to reverse: ");
    fgets(s,50,stdin);
    ps=strrev(s);
    strcpy(s2,ps); //copy contents to a string array
    //i did the copy because using printf("%s", ps); did the same thing

    printf("Reversed string: %s\n", s2); //PECULIAR, s2 enters line feed char in s2[0]

    //test loop to determine the inserted character
    while(1){
        if(s2[i]==10) {printf("is 10,%d", i); break;}; //the proof of LF
        if(s2[i]==12) {printf("is 12"); break;};
        if(s2[i]==13) {printf("is 13"); break;};
        if(s2[i]==15) {printf("is 15"); break;};
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){ //determine where the characters are positioned
        printf("%c: %d\n", s2[i], s2[i]);
        if(s2[i]=='\0') break;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

By running this program and entering the string....let's say "**darts**" will reverse the string in the array that will have the elements s2[0]=**'\012'**=10(decimal), ...strad..., s2[7]='\0'.
Is it normal for strrev to behave as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets` stores the newline in the string. So when you `strrev`, `\n` (linefeed) will be the first element.

> The [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) function shall read bytes from stream into the array
>   pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a  **is read
>   and transferred to s**.

**EDIT**

Just tested it on Visual Studio:

```
char a[] = "abcd\n";
strrev(a);

printf("%d\n", a[0]); /* 10 */
```

Comment: actually \0 is the first character and then the new line. strrev preserves the new line.

Comment: @0A0D My implementation doesn't have `strrev`. Do you perchance have some documentation that states `\0` will be the first character ?

Comment: http://www.warpspeed.com.au/cgi-bin/inf2html.cmd?..\html\book\Toolkt40\XPG4REF.INF+275 (use whole link - don't click)

Comment: @0A0D See my edit. We must be having different implementations of `strrev`. Although an implementation that leaves `\0` as the first character is a bit strange methinks.

Comment: Well, who really knows what the OP is talking about because he just corrected himself in @Als answer by saying he really meant 10 decimal not \010.

Comment: My bad, i was confusing octal with decimal. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`strrev` reverses the order of the characters in the given string. The ending null character `\0` remains in place.

`fgets` is storing the newline in this case.

Comment: Well this isn't about \0 it is about \010 LINE FEED charachter

Comment: @Andrew: You need to understand char arrays. The last character is null-terminator, second to last is the new line (e.g. \010)!

Comment: @Als: so fgets is the cause of this. Thanks for feedback but read carefull next time and do not vote and comment randomly please.

Comment: @Andrew G.H.: Do not vote and comment randomly? I neither downvoted you, I never do actually, and I never wrote any comment.

Comment: @0A0D: I do know what a char array is. The question is : "Where did the \010 come from?"..the answer was: "fgets inserts the \010". Read carefully next time.

Comment: @Andrew: WTF are you talking about? We are trying to help you.

Comment: @Andrew: \010 is not a newline!

Comment: @Als: Oh, my bad. When i said commenting i meant answering the question. You obviously rushed the first time.

Comment: @All: ah yes, pardon me, \012 (Octal) = 10 (decimal)

Comment: @Andrew: You see the problem? You gave us bad information. How are we supposed to answer your question with bad information?

Comment: @Andrew G.H.: Hope you understand the problem & as for the rush, It was right on since the first time i posted.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` stores the newline character in the char array as the last character. strrev will keep this character along with the null-terminated character (e.g. \010). ASCII 10 is newline. The string is null terminated (`\0`), so `strrev` is just taking the null-terminated `char` array and reversing it. If you don't want the null terminated character, then remove it. `strrev` reverses the order of the characters in the given string. The ending null character (\0) remains in place.

Comment: As i said, it is about \010 LINE FEED not....\0. strrev does not reverse \0 and does not what so ever have to do anything with a line feed. Read carefully.

Comment: @Andrew: \010 is not line feed. \0 is null terminator and 10 is ASCII for newline!